# Random select is taking too much memory in Python

Tags: python, random

I am trying to select lines to read from a CSV file, selection is based on:

```
n = 123456789    
s = n//10
# skip value will be used with skip_row in pd.read_csv
skip = sorted(random.sample(range(1, n+1), k=(n-s))
```

This line is causing the script to crash due to the high RAM usage. The file size is close to 5 GB, and this why randomly reading 10% of it is needed.
The expectation is that random.select will not take too much memory, surprisingly it does (goes up to 5 GB and even more, as task manager shows)

Is there an efficient way to select the rows to be skipped.

Comment: It's halting the computer? That sounds unlikely. Also, edit your question to describe what you're trying to do, what happens, what you expect to happen, etc. Take a look at [ask]

Comment: @Mohd It sound like your problem is with size of the file, which you put into a memory, not with select function.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzczesiak this is a problem of memory as the file size is close to 5 GB. And this is why I need to use random select.

Comment: @pvg It is halting the PC due to high RAM usage, the RAM has been growing during run and the PC became unresponsive, thus, I had to shut it down from the power button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the comments, I managed to write a code that finds all the n=123456789 labels/samples in 31 seconds (using Core i5 PC), here it is:

```
import random 
import time

start_time = time.time()

n=123456789
 if n>123456789:
      step_size = int(1e7)
 else:
      step_size=n//10
no_of_steps = n//step_size-1
s= step_size//10

xx=list(); i=0

while (i<no_of_steps):
     xx= xx + sorted(random.sample(range(i*step_size, (i+1)*step_size-1), k= s))
     i +=1

print("Size of selected samples", len(xx))
print("Percentage achieved", len(xx)/n)
print("Time needed to pick 10% from ", n, "samples is:" , time.time()-start_time)
print("-------- \n Show a few samples", xx[:10], '...', xx[-10:])
```

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, your current method is very heavy. It's really trying to store and work on (sample+sort) an array of 123,456,789 python integers in memory. I don't believe you actually need the "skip" rows in an array in advance. If that's so, you could instead use a `generator`. Here's how you could go about `generating` your sample set instead:

```
def random_sampler_generator(input_seq, skip_chance=0.5):
    for i in input_seq:
        if random.random() > skip_chance:
            yield i

for m in random_sampler_generator(xrange(1, n+1), skip_chance=0.1):
    print m
```

It's a good bit slower because it's instead calling random.random() more than 100 million times but it's extremely memory efficient thanks to the `yield` function. You should probably also be using `xrange` in lieu of `range` for the exact same reason.

Here, `random_sampler_generator` uses a heuristic method of sampling in that you're not guaranteed to have `X%` but the result will tend towards it as the input set size grows. `skip_chance` expects a float between 0 and 1 where .1 is 10% skipped, .5 is 50% skipped, and .75 is 75% skipped, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You want a random subset of your data, but you complain the data is too large to be memory resident. So use external sort to get your data into suitable shape.

Read all N of your records from `source.csv`, prepend a random value from a PRNG or SHA1 of a counter or (for unique records) SHA1 of each record, and send the N result records to either `/usr/bin/sort` or an indexed table in a relational database.

Now your records appear on disk in a random order, and you can easily perform your 1st experiment by reading the first S records, with no memory impact. Remember where you left off, and you can perform your 2nd experiment by reading the next S records. Or, another approach would be to ask for the first S records where the initial SHA1 nybble is '3', another with the first S records starting with '5', and so on. Your experimental design will not have to worry about randomly encountering the same source record in multiple experiments, as you have created non-overlapping partitions.

EDIT: Producing random indexes without replacement is different from producing random folds of experimental data. The request was to conserve memory. This approach works fast, with limited memory (never allocating proportional to `s`), using the CSV input the OP question specified. Tail -4 gives the results at the end, prepend runs on OP required data size in five minutes (302 sec), and this sort runs in about a minute (77 sec):

```
$ time env LC_ALL=C gsort --parallel=8 /tmp/rand.csv > /tmp/shuffled.csv

#! /usr/bin/env python3

import base64
import csv
import hashlib
import re
import time


def prepend(infile, outfile):
    """Turns the input CSV into one that has hex hashes in column 1."""
    with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, 'w') as fout:
        insheet = csv.reader(fin)
        outsheet = csv.writer(fout)
        for i, word in insheet:
            hex = hashlib.sha224(word.encode()).hexdigest()[:12]
            outsheet.writerow((hex, i, word))


def gen(outfile, n=123456789, seed='foo'):
    num_word_re = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]\w{7})')
    just_alnum = str.maketrans('', '', '+/')
    with open(outfile, 'w') as fout:
        sheet = csv.writer(fout)
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            sha = hashlib.sha224(f'{seed}{str(i)}'.encode())
            dig = sha.digest()
            text = base64.b64encode(dig).decode()
            m = num_word_re.search(text.translate(just_alnum))
            sheet.writerow((i, str(dig[-1] % 10) + m.group(1)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    big = '/tmp/big.csv'
    gen(big)
    t0 = time.time()
    prepend(big, '/tmp/rand.csv')
    print('%.3f sec.' % (time.time() - t0))

==> /tmp/rand.csv <==
b784b9e91557,123456786,8vdzlXU0k
6b545b9a8be8,123456787,1tfemzO0R
40ae0bfea89b,123456788,0Ua8LYuK8
c461c832b5aa,123456789,0y91nshi6

==> /tmp/shuffled.csv <==
ffffff1db601,117611393,3TCHPS1tD
ffffff3d6962,110031982,7jzzKwrNz
ffffff468062,20413362,6juuxuPN2
ffffff81de0a,102223550,2p91NhYXq
```

Comment: The problem is that the file is too large to fit into memory, and this is why I needed to use random.select, to skip_rows later.